# "Makes you stay more productive" vs "Makes you more productive"

Tags: sentence-structure

> 1.A vacation makes you stay more productive.
>
> 2.A vacation makes you more productive.

I know these 2 sentences are pretty much the same, but I'd like to know the subtle difference. For me, sentence 1 sounds like more natural because it is more obvious that 'you' is a subject of action or state 'stay more productive'. If you had to choose one favorite expression, what would you choose? And how about followings?

> a. A vacation helps you stay more productive.
>
> b. A vacation helps you more productive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I know these 2 sentences are pretty much the same...*. Are they the same? I see one very different from the other!

Comment: b) is ungrammatical. You need to add "be":  A vacation helps you [to] be (or become) more productive.

Answer (score 1):

You might "stay more" productive than someone else, but you cannot "stay more" productive than yourself.

A vacation can allow you to remain productive. Stay productive.

A vacation refreshes you. If your productivity has waned because of burn-out or job-weariness, a vacation can bring you back to your former level of productivity. So your productivity increases to its former level.  Or a vacation can keep you from getting burnt-out.

In this process there is either a sense of change or *becoming* (recuperation) or of *maintaining a level*.  *Stay more* makes no sense in either scenario: *stay* does not jibe with becoming, and *more* does not jibe with maintaining.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. A vacation makes you stay more productive.
> 2. A vacation makes you more productive.
>
> *If you had to choose one favorite expression, what would you choose?*

This is a case where both expressions are grammatical, so we really need to be careful about getting into the business of choosing a "favorite." When two sentences are equally grammatical and neither is especially jarring, **context** determines when one might be chosen over the other.

For example, if I was writing an article entitled *Ways to Become More Productive*, then #2 might be a better fit. However, if the headline of my self-help article was, *Ways to Remain Productive*, then #1 might be a better fit.

As a footnote, if I was writing the article called *Ways to Remain Productive*, I might use the sentence structure in #2, but change the verb:

> A vacation **keeps** you more productive.

Comment: Yes. "Make stay" doesn't sound 'desirable' to my ears too.